# My `pdf` generated through RTD is having all articles of content in the heading content Why?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I have just recently (yesterday) started using sphinx and read the docs for my [project](http://github.com/arcxon/todx).

Till now I am happy with the Html documentation but the pdf version includes all the articles That appear in the index within the Contents heading. And the Documents orignal content/index is simply comprised of two links.

Please help.

The documentation is at http://todx.rtfd.io and the pdf is [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/todx/latest/todx.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

When generating the PDF, Sphinx is always adding the content that is referenced via a `.. toctree::` directive exactly where the directive is placed.
In contrast, when generating HTML, Sphinx is placing the content **after** the file that contains the `toctree`.

In this aspect, PDF generation and HTML generation are simply inconsistent.

Thus, you should place all content of the index page **before** the table of contents.

In case you want to provide an overview of the most important sections inline, you can use a list of [references](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations). Then, you might want to hide the `toctree` using the `hidden` property, for example like this:

```
Contents
--------

- :ref:`quickstart`
- :ref:`userguide`

Features
--------

- Fast
- Simple
- Inituitive
- Easy to Use
- Offline
- Open Source

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   quickstart
   userguide
```